How can I make auto-complete systemd unit names be case-insenstive?
Bash auto-complete helped immensely with the php-like naming conventions to systemd unit names. It completely solves the mix of Kebab-case, snake_case, camelCase.
But I still get frustrated with things like getting the case of the first letter wrong. t<tab><tab>...sigh...<backspace>T<tab>Thunderbolt... B<tab><tab>...sigh...<backspace>b<tab>bluetooth... and don't even get me started on the networkmanager rename :)
I see the bash-completion files uses systemctl $1 list-units --all "$2*";
What's the best way to make that nocaseglob-like?

There are 2 possibilities: make list-units list all units and do the anycase matching later in the pipeline,  or convert the $2* glob into an anycase glob.
To start with, we'll just show the current code from your link, re-indented
for legibility:
__get_all_units(){
 { __systemctl $1 list-unit-files "$2*"
   __systemctl $1 list-units --all "$2*"
 } |
 { while read -r a b
   do echo " $a"
   done
 }
}

They should probably be using printf rather than echo but we'll ignore that.
For the first solution, remove the "$2*" twice, and change the while
loop:
__get_all_units(){
 { __systemctl $1 list-unit-files
   __systemctl $1 list-units --all
 } |
 { shopt -s nocasematch
   while read -r a b
   do if [[ "$a" == $2* ]]
      then echo " $a"
      fi
   done
 }
}

This works, but is rather slow on my system, as systemd does a lot of work
on each unit.
For the second solution, create a function to replace a glob pattern like
n by [nN], so that both cases are matched.
myanycaseglob(){
 local pat=$1 len=${#1} result i ch
 for i in $(eval echo {0..$(($len-1))})
 do ch=${pat:$i:1}
    if [[ "$ch" == [a-zA-Z] ]]
    then result="$result[${ch,*}${ch^*}]"
    else result="$result$ch"
    fi
 done
 echo "$result"
}

The above takes each character and uses bash's ${ch,*} to convert it to
lowercase or ${ch^*} uppercase.
Then the function to list matches is simply:
__get_all_units() { 
 local anywant=$(myanycaseglob "$2")
 { __systemctl $1 list-unit-files "$anywant*" 
   __systemctl $1 list-units --all "$anywant*"
 } |
 { while read -r a b; do echo " $a"; done; }
}


great answer! but there's one systemd hack that foils the plan COMPREPLY=($(compgen -o filenames -W '$comps' -- "$cur_orig")) from https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/040cb66458e7a06c759569c08948188296c267fe/shell-completion/bash/systemctl.in#L256-L271 ...it filters everything again and excludes our globcase. Can't find how to make that one case insensitive besides replicating the anymatch workdaround there too

That is an added complication. I haven't tested, but can we just short-circuit the code and add COMPREPLY=($comps); return 0 after line 283 if that is the only case that matters?

that fills the "answer prompt" with all the options at once. I think I would have to complicate it further with grep/awk/sed/cut... to get only the shorter common prefix.
